# What is "string-map" in scheme?

Tags: scheme

When I look at the code below, I see syntax "string-map". And I don't understand what it mean. Can you anyone please explain it? Thank you!

```
(define (convert-nucleotide nuc)
  (case nuc)
    ((#\C) #\G)
    ((#\G) #\C)
    ((#\A) #\U)
    ((#\T) #\A)))
(define (to-rna dna)
  (string-map convert-nucleotide dna))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SRFI-13 `string-map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-13.html#string-map) is a procedure that takes a procedure and a input string as argument.

The string is iterated by passing each character to the procedure and it is expected that the procedure will return/evaluate to the new character which is used in the returned string.

Example:

```
(char-ucase #\a)                ; ==> #\A)
(string-map char-upcase "test") ; ==> "TEST"`
```